# Repeat asynchronous requests to the server

Tags: multithreading, scala, future

What I want to do is repeat GET requests to a server asynchronously over and over again so that I can synchronize the local data with the remote one. I'd like to do this by using `Future`s **without involving akka** because I just want to understand the basic idea of how to do that at the lower level. No `async` and `await` preferably either because they are kind of the high level functions for `Futures` and `Promises`, thus I'd like to use `Futures` and `Promises` themselves.

So this is my functions:

```
def sendHttpRequestToServer(): String = { ... }

def send: Unit = {
  val f = future { sendHttpRequestToServer() }
  f onComplete {
    case Success(x) => 
      processResult(x)      // do something with result "x"
      send                  // delay if needed and send the request again
    case onFailure(e) =>
      logException(e)
      send                  // send the request again
  }  
}
```

That's what I think it might be. How could I change it, is there any mistake in algorithm? Your thoughts.

**UPDATE:**

As I already know, futures are not designed for recurring tasks, only for one time ones. Therefore, they can't be used here. What do I use then?

Answer (score 3):

Your code has some issues with exception handling. If an exception is thrown in `processResult` or `logException` the `send` will no longer occur, breaking your loop. This exception will also not be logged. A better way is:

```
f.map(processResult).onFailure(logException)
f.onComplete(x => send())
```

This way the `send` still happens despite exceptions in `processResult` or `logException`, exceptions from `processResult` are logged, and the next send can begin intermediately while the results are still being processed. If you want to wait until processing is complete, you could do:

```
val f2 = f.map(processResult).recover { case e => logException(e) }
f2.onComplete(x => send())
```

Comment: but how do you know whether processResult and logException have try ... catch blocks or not?

Comment: I don't. This way I don't have to know, and processResult won't need its own separate try/catch/call to `logException`, so the code is DRYer.

Comment: I don't think that if processResult and logException don't have try ... catch then the code DRYer. Why do you think so?

Comment: Because you will be repeating the exception handling logic in multiple places. `processResult` would require a try/catch block calling `logException`, whereas it is DRYer to funnel all exceptions to a single call to `logException`, as I did above.